# Kerberos Delegation for Clients Ouside the Firewall

Tags: sql-server, internet-explorer, iis, kerberos, delegation

I am trying to run a SQL Server Reporting Services where the data for the report is on a SQL Server database that's on a different server.  Integrated Authentication is turned on for both the Report Server and the report.  I have confirmed that Kerberos delegation is working fine by using Internet Explorer to run the report from inside the network.

However, when I open the report server through the firewall, I cannot run the report.  I get the following error: An error has occurred during report processing.  Cannot create a connection to data source 'frattoxppro2'.  Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

Does Kerberos authentication *not* work outside a firewall?

Answer (score 5):

Kerberos requires a port 88 connection to the KDC, in this case, most likely your DC.

What you probably want to look at is HTTPS + Basic Authentication + Protocol Transition to take the Basic Authentication and translate it into a DC based Kerberos Ticket for delegation and back end authentication.

- [Protocol Transition with
  Constrained Delegation Technical
  Supplement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480585.aspx)
- [How To: Use Protocol Transition and
  Constrained Delegation in
  ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998355.aspx)

Not exactly the easiest to set up, but when its working, it works amazingly well.

Comment: Do you know by any chance if this is possible in Java?  (Protocol transition)

Comment: If you're talking about a java client to a windows server, I would think it wouldn't be an issue since the Protocol Transition happens at the server after the (java) client authenticated.  For a Java-based server, no idea.

Comment: Actually it is not possible (or I don't know how). Switched to .Net and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really in a position to tell you why kerberos isn't working for you, but did have a alternative suggestion for your configuration. You can use ISA services to expose the reporting server rather than simply poking a hole in your firewall. This is something our company has done successfully - it republishes the reporting services site so the browsers are talking to ISA, not directly to the server. ISA Services is quite happy to pass through your credentials as well.